# Parse rendered content from wordpress to flutter

Tags: android, wordpress, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

Thanks in advance.
Currently i'm developing a blog to flutter app and i have problems in parsing the rendered content that is returned from wp-json api. Everything works fine with library [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) 
but it is not able to render youtube and twitter embedded content  properly.
Is there any library or way available to render Youtube and Twitter content from wordpress api to flutter widget properly.

```
Html(
  data: mNewsData,
  showImages: isLoadImages ? true : false,
  defaultTextStyle: isDarkMode
  ? TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontSize: theme.getTextSize())
   : TextStyle(fontSize: theme.getTextSize()),
  onLinkTap: (url) {
  launch(url);
 },
)
```

where mNewsData is response data from wordpress with context enum "view"

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to render both YouTube and Twitter content ?